# Textbox not adding to the StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found incorrect piece of code in my work yesterday. I was adding 2 different types of `Texboxes` to the same list. When I change one of the names of the properties they now don't appear in the `StackPanel`.

Let me show you, This is my working property, when I Click a button it adds a title `Textbox` to the `Stackpanel`:

```
ObservableCollection<string> _title = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Title
{
    get { return _title; }
    set
    {
        _title = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => Title);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, when I click a button it adds the title `Texbox` to the `StackPanel`. When I try and do it for a question `Textbox` it wont work:

```
ObservableCollection<string> _questions = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Questions
{
    get { return _questions; }
    set
    {
        _questions = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => Questions);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it wont add as I have debugged the code for both the **title** and the **question** and they do exactly the same?

Does anyone know the error that I am making in my code?

EDIT:

```
public ViewModel()
{
        this.AddQuestionCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>((o) => OnAddQuestion()));
        this.AddTitleCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>((o) => OnAddTitle()));
}

private void OnAddQuestion()
{
        this.Questions.Add("Question...");
}

private void OnAddTitle()
{
        this.Title.Add("Title...");
}
```

```
        <ListView x:Name="QuestionList" ItemsSource="{Binding Question}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Template}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="40,20,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
```

EDIT 2:

```
    ViewModel _viewModel = new ViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
```

Comment: You should perhaps show the code where you *actually* add the TextBox.

Comment: @Clemens Do you need the XAML?

Comment: XAML if you add textboxes in xaml. Otherwise code-behind.

Comment: @interneo Edited code with XAML

Comment: Do you set DataContext for this ListView?

Comment: @interneo Nope, just the ItemsSource and Template.

Comment: @interneo My bad, I am setting the Datacontext in C# code in my edit

Comment: @user3157821 Your property is 'Questions' not 'Question' - it's probably the problem source

Comment: @interneo My stupid mistake, sorry. If you post answer I will vote as correct. My bad. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is 'Questions' not 'Question' - it's probably the problem source

Answer (score 1):

Your error is clearly not in the code that you have shown here. Apart from the names, the two code examples are the same. So if one is working and the other is not, then something else is broken somewhere else. This also stands for the code in your first edit. You just need to look at the two *full* examples (including the XAML) and see what is different.

Please read through the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page from the Help Center, which should help you to provide better code examples. Often, following these guidelines can lead to you solving your own problems as well.

Comment: Thanks will take a look at the link now and will post on the question will I have solved my issue.